The water in my tank level on my toilet will not go down far enough to suck the flapper back into place what can I do to remedy this?
So I know that my toilet is adjusted correctly right now but even with the flapper held all the way open the tank does not get low enough for the the flapper to fall back into place and seal it just floats around in the water. What can I do to remedy this is there anything too remedy of this other than replacing the toilet?

Check that the holes under the rim are open and not clogged with years of scale and lime from the water.

adjust the chain attached to flapper, lengthen it, or shorten it

Partly closing the supply valve, to reduce the rate at which the tank refills, might help...

this could happen if the fapper position needs adjustment.
in your case it is lifted to high, and it does not get pulled down by draining force
to fix adjust the hight of the flapper
